# How to troubleshoot VS2010 Build Mode errors

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Sorry,  I'm not sure how to phrase this question. I have a issue where I'm building a VS21010 Solution in both debug/Mixed CPU and in release. From what I can tell in the Configuration Manager all projects are set to build in Debug/Mixed CPU. However in my automated build t also builds for release/x64 and this is where it's failing. I get the error that "Project is not selected to build for this solution configuration".

Here is what the errors look like:

------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: ITT_Reset, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------ Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

------ Rebuild All started: Project: Presenters (PresentationLayer\Presenters\Presenters), Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

No way to resolve conflict between "log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" and "log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304". Choosing "log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" arbitrarily.

CommonDialogs\ReportViewer\VitalsHistoryReport\VitalsHistory.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box `Textbox1' and the line`Line2' overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

CommonDialogs\ReportViewer\VitalsHistoryReport\VitalsHistory.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box `Textbox1' and the line`Line1' overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

CommonDialogs\ReportViewer\VitalsHistoryReport\VitalsHistory.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box `Textbox1' and the text box`Textbox27' overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

CommonDialogs\ReportViewer\VitalsHistoryReport\VitalsHistory.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box `Textbox1' and the text box`Textbox14' overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

CommonDialogs\ReportViewer\VitalsHistoryReport\VitalsHistory.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box `Textbox1' and the text box`Textbox29' overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

CommonDialogs\ReportViewer\VitalsHistoryReport\VitalsHistory.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box `Textbox1' and the text box`Textbox34' overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3540,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Workspaces\AHLTA\Current\Product\CommonBin\Dod.Chcsii.Shared.ITT_Reset.dll" because it was not found.

COPYEXECENV=N

COMSUPPORT=N

------ Rebuild All started: Project: Views (PresentationLayer\Views\Views), Configuration: Release Any CPU ------ LC : warning LC0000: 'Unable to find assembly 'C:\Workspaces\AHLTA\Current\Product\CommonBin\Dod.Ahlta.PresentationLayer.Presenters.dll'

LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Keyoti.RapidSpell.NET2.TXSupportv21, Version=5.2.14.1110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58d9fd2e9ec4dc0e' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))'

Comment: Looks like your reference paths, or reference DLLs are not configured....Whenever 'could not load file or assembly' errors occur, one or more DLLs are missing....Don't forget extra dependencies not directly used too

Comment: ie, Ignore the other warnings, fix the 'not found' stuff first

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow :)

Comment: Build > Configuration Manager.  Select the Release configuration, tick what projects should be built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a few problems:

1. The libraries you want to use like `Dod.Chcsii.Shared.ITT_Reset.dll` may not be x64.  You can only include libraries that are the same number of bits as your Project, i.e. 32 bit or 64 bit (or 16 bit). So lock in your Project to either 32 or 64 bit (if you use 3rd party DLLs).
2. Looks like your reference paths, or reference DLLs are not configured. Whenever 'could not load file or assembly' errors occur, one or more DLLs are missing. Don't forget extra dependencies not directly used too - where a DLL you use directly, may also need 10 more DLLs under the covers.
3. Ignore the other warnings, fix the 'not found' stuff first.
4. Use PROJECT references instead of DLL references wherever possible.  This should sync the version conflicts better.  Or else re-compile your own DLLs that are consumed by this Project.

Comment: I noticed that under the release mode x64 configuration there were 2 projects (ITT_Reset being one of them) that was not set to build under x64. I checked off both and I'm running a build now.  Hopefully that will fix the issue.